# HFS+ Read access in Windows

Tags: windows, hfs+

I need to read and write some files on a HFS+ (Mac) partitioned drive and wondering is there any APIs for that already made, googleing didn't come up with anything. If not, how does one approach this problem from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API, just drivers. I would recommend you to learn how to use google. ;) It's the very first hit.

Try [Macdrive](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive/standard/)
or [paragon sw](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/)

Comment: $19.95?! That's a fortune. I'm sure the OP would rather spend the next three years writing their own HFS+ driver.

Comment: Not the point in price at all, I need to write to the disk from my app, not manually using 3rd party software.

Comment: Ah, i understand. You should rephrase your question to avoid answers like this. I'm sorry, but there isn't anything like that. Writing to a filesystem is to comprehensive to let an app handle it.